# Why do all these contradictory problems exist on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

[PHP 5.6, MySQL, SSL and self-signed certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424518/php-5-6-mysql-ssl-and-self-signed-certificates)

- Why are these people always ready to answer the 1000000th stupid question on a silly syntax error but close, due to some formal reason, a really useful post they can't even understand?
- Why do these people tell the OP to add an answer and at the same time take away his ability to?
- Why do people never think when they act?
- Why will nothing would happen to this unfortunate post unless someone writes a hatepost on Meta to draw attention manually? Where is your vaunted automation and community?
- Why are people still concerned about stupid things like score and badges but not quality and knowledge?
- Why is Google still showing outdated but highly upvoted crap from '09 instead of more recent and correct answers?
- Why celebrate the 10000000th post? Does it really add to knowledge?
- Why is the site's only purpose to serve passers-by with quick and dirty answers? It is up for 7 years already and nobody cares to follow the declared goal of improving knowledge, but only to add more and more stupid questions? Or - even worse - to follow mechanically, by torpedoing good posts due to overly-formal reasons?
- Why did fun and gamification pass from just a seasoning to become the only guidelines?
- Why is there still no bonus for finding a duplicate?
- Why is a good answer a very rare accident, not the rule?
- Why is there no delay between posting a question and the ability to answer, to let the few who care find a duplicate?
- Why is the administration scared to death by users, each useful feature either torpedoed due to potential abuse or, being implemented at last, hobbled by a thousand restrictions?

Comment: <bullet> ***Why*** so many questions?

Comment: I've re-opened the question and left a comment for them.

Comment: Don't bother to answer? Then what was the point?

Comment: The answer to the last question is the first question.

Comment: Welcome back! Though I'm curious, what is *your* vision for how SO should be?

Comment: I think this is not far from the famous self answered questions. They are said to be welcome here but the question **must** be a correct one, even if OP already knows the solution. And even if it is correct, you can be sure that it has no hope for upvotes nor many views (unless written by Jon Skeet, Martijn Pieters or some others  (rare) well know names). It would be more honest to say : never self answer immediately, but ask a real question and only answer after a while

Comment: _Why these people tell the OP...Why google still showing...Why still no..._ - Man, Jadakiss' latest remix is not good at all.

Comment: Why so much vitriol? You seriously think this will do any good to anyone? you just get pissed for no reason. Calm down, bring suggestions to the table, work WITH the system. God knows it has its flaws, but if all you do is scream at it, not much will happen...

Comment: Good work, Colonel. Age has not impaired your efficiency in the least.

Comment: @Tim why reopen? OP clearly says he's not interested in answer i.e. it's just a rant.

Comment: @Sha, because Tim doesn't want his answer to remain locked into being the only reply to the Colonel, so he allowed us and/or him to provide a counter-point if we wish to do so? :)

Comment: Man you guys are awful at following instructions. No wonder this site is doomed to fail. You were right, Colonel.

Comment: Ok, that title sucks big time (the one on the linked question).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, why vote to close to demonstrate you understand the relative futility in answering a question whose author says they do not want answers, *and edit that precision out of the question at the same time*? That does not compute.

Comment: I voted to close as too broad since I [guesstimated](https://www.google.com/#q=guesstimated) *(wow, that's really a word! sweet)* that there were 12 different questions you asked. There are definitely some questions in there, that if expanded on, would make good feature-requests or discussions.

Answer (score 25):

Coupla things ...

> Why will nothing would happen to this unfortunate post unless someone writes a hatepost on Meta to draw attention manually? Where is your vaunted automation and community?

Well, it doesn't have to be a hate post; even though you're really frustrated, it could have been as simple as *Someone obviously doesn't understand how the self-answer thing works, and instead of helping them, we just shut it down and made them feel bad for trying. Can we fix this please by reopening it?*

> Why is there still no bonus for finding a duplicate?

Because I can't come up with a bonus that is *greater* than the rep folks might earn by knowingly answering a duplicate.

However, let's say we have a silver / gold badge, and the gold version is named 'deduplicator (participated in marking 500 duplicate questions)', I *could* unlock some privileges for the people who earned it, maybe access to Thor's hammer? It's something I've been thinking about lately, and I'm open to thoughts.

> Why celebrate the 10000000th post? Does it really add to knowledge?

Nope, but every single day people put *thousands* of hours into writing answers to people's questions. They want to celebrate, and we'd be insensitive, willy-nilly gobstopping überclods if we didn't help make that happen :)

Now, finally, the assertions you make in your points do a very good job of illustrating how *you* see the site, and the feedback (while somewhat abrupt) is valuable. You're active in one of the most problematic tags on the site (PHP/MySQL); *this isn't a universal problem*.

I have been looking at ways to help curtail the river of crap that flows through PHP down the iOS peninsula on its way to Androidville, since all tags aren't really equal in the kinds of quality problems they exhibit.

*You have good ideas*, *you have a good perspective*, the question is, can you do something constructive with those things? I'd love to see you participate here *beyond* stopping by to shoot bullets at the wall :)

Or, well, keep doing that if you want, but you'll definitely see more improvements if you work more with us.

Comment: +1 for *"willy-nilly gobstopping uberclods"* because it made me laugh. But I still think this post should have stayed closed and been deleted. He obviously knows that posting a bunch of questions in a rant isn't helpful. As you know, this isn't the place to just gripe when you're upset but for sincere questions and potentially helpful suggestions.

Comment: @codeMagic Eh, he's a Colonel, Colonels love their bullets. More seriously, his view of the site _is_ how he states it, but that doesn't make it representative of the _majority_ of the site, and that's something that I wanted to address. That and the other more interesting points he brought up.

Comment: If this isn't a universal problem, what tag *does* perfectly exemplify all of SE's values? I haven't seen it.

Comment: @Tim I get that. I just wanted to bring out the point of *why* you reopened and answered as to not encourage this type of post (especially for new visitors of meta).

Comment: @bjb568: no tag is perfect. But some tags are further from perfection than others. A *lot* further.

Comment: @codeMagic While it is to a large extent a rant, he made me want to write stuff and he has some valid points. I get your concern about answering this inviting more, but I've been here _quite_ a while, not many people get _this_ frustrated _while leaving so much evidence that they're uniquely qualified to solve very hard problems_. If this was just "Screw you people!" I would not have bothered.

Comment: @Martijn There are still issues that can be seen on any tag that do need to be addressed. One of these is the rep system rewarding crap answerers.

Answer (score -1):

My thoughts on some points of your dissatisfaction...

> Why are people still concerned about stupid things like score... but not quality and knowledge?

Because of the knowledge-hostile reputation system. It's designed for quick fluctuation, satisfication and to cause addiction - similar playing a mmorpg and earning exp. Generating and supporting so called "reputation hunters" or knowledge-fragment spammers that are spoiling the real fun. But as of SOs success it possibly won't be changed too much in the near term.

> Why good answer is a very rare accident but not rule?

Because good answers require more research, deeper understanding and effort which is not rewarded as much.

What can be done?

- Stay true to oneself and support understanding regardless of rep or what others are doing.
- Don't take part in the rep game, don't upvote spammers but upvote interesting stuff.
- Don't let oneself being discouraged from posting an interesting answer that cost time and effort, even if "working code" has beend posted already. Good answers often still get rewarded.
- Change to another community that's more focused on research and understanding.

That's my opinion as one who appreciates SO and it's community. After all I have improved my knowledge and understanding as there is enough interesting answers out there.

Comment: In my experience, the good answers *always* get more votes than the code-only ones. Maybe [tag:c#] is unique that way, but people do appreciate quality over speed

Comment: I originally felt your answer wasn't a very good one. (It read to me as just another rant to answer this rant.) After your edits today, it reads far more constructively in my eyes, particularly the addition of the "What can be done?" section. Great work!

Answer (score -12):

Because users are humans. Look at how many useless jobs there are in this world: investment bankers, lawyers, public servants in your local area that tell you that you can not build this & you can not build that in a city suffers severe housing shortage. Software provider that re-write every thing every second year and make users fork out 10+% time for upgrades that people don't really need.

In a society that worships money, people will do all kinds of silly things for money.

On a website that promotes reps, people will do all kinds of dumb things for reps.

Simple as that.

If it's any comfort, cockroach or virus would likely to be the winner specie when a nuclear war took place or a large asteroid hit earth, not human. Not human at current stage at least.

Comment: Cockroaches as a whole species being able to survive a nuclear blast is [a well-known hoax](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7912/can-cockroaches-survive-a-nuclear-war). I also sincerely doubt they would be able to survive direct collision with large asteroids. Your statement about doing dumb things for money / rep is quite right, though.

Comment: I said 'would likely to be the winner' ... also I said 'cockroach or virus'. I stand correct.