# Close vote and voting rights

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, users, abuse

Does the voting rights of a person get revoked if they close vote on every question that they encounter?

What do we do if we know such persons which the system can verify?

Comment: It's possible, if a moderator decides they are abusing it and said abuse is repeated, and they deem the abuse worthy of suspension. there is no removal of just one privilege, it's all or nothing (with the exception of asking, answering, and reviewing, which each have their own automated "bans")

Comment: @KevinB: How does the moderator get notified. Is there a list which shows the offense and possible action to be taken?

Comment: They'd get notified via a flag by normal users, or a meta post. (ideally a flag, we don't like targeting users here)

Comment: the best punishment for such a user is that most of indiscriminately voted questions stay open (they really do, you can test that yourself)

Comment: There is no automatic removal of rights, if that's what you mean, but if bad behavioral patterns are seen, then action might be taken. The system can detect some bad voting behaviors, such as when one user gives another multiple up-votes or down-votes, especially if performed in rapid succession, but other more subtle voting behaviors would probably require flags to the moderators for the moderators to able to identify problems and then perform corrective actions on them.

Comment: some question get without faukl closed voted, for exact and good reasons, that is not abuse, but you can post the question or question so that we cqan see if  you follow your assessment

Comment: The number of close votes per day is limited so nobody could close all the questions that occur on Stack Overflow in one day, there are simply too many of them.

Comment: *What do we do if we know such persons which the system can verify?* ... What we always do if we come across persons that do things we don't like: Call them out on Meta and bring on the pitchforks ....

Comment: I don't think that even an <expletive deleted>hole like me closes every question they encounter.

Comment: Generally we'd complement someone who close voted a lot as they are trying to maintain high standards of quality. They are also helping the OP, either by explaining what's wrong with the question or pointing to a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please, is anything going to be done about the pedantic question closers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299394/please-is-anything-going-to-be-done-about-the-pedantic-question-closers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does the voting rights of a person get revoked if they close vote on every question that they encounter?

Not that I'm aware of and I've close voted a bunch of questions without any repercussions.

With close vote privileges and a dupe hammer you can single handedly close 50 questions per day, basically unnoticed and hardly anyone cares. Except for that poor asker that sees their hope for a tailored answer shattered by a single duplicate vote.

Comment: dupe hammer is granted to those who did many well received answers in the tag. This means, their power to close is naturally balanced by proven preference and ability to answer the (worthy) questions in the tag instead of closing them